# Create a dummy variable based on lagged combination of multiple other variables - R

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, group

Say I have the following data:

| date | employee | company | rolename | company_conglomerate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-12-2008 | X | A | manager | 1 |
| 31-12-2008 | Y | B | manager | 0 |
| 31-12-2008 | Z | C | manager | 0 |
| 31-12-2009 | Y | A | CEO | 1 |
| 31-12-2009 | X | B | CEO | 0 |
| 31-12-2009 | Z | C | CEO | 0 |

Based on the above data, I want to create a new dummy variable that is equal to 1 if a CEO has prior experience working at a conglomerate company, and 0 otherwise.

| date | employee | company | rolename | company_conglomerate | CEO_prior_conglomerate_experience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-12-2008 | X | A | manager | 1 | 0 |
| 31-12-2008 | Y | B | manager | 0 | 0 |
| 31-12-2008 | Z | C | manager | 0 | 0 |
| 31-12-2009 | Y | A | CEO | 1 | 0 |
| 31-12-2009 | X | B | CEO | 0 | 1 |
| 31-12-2009 | Z | C | CEO | 0 | 0 |

Notice that employee X switches from company A to company B, and employee Y switches from company B to company A. Both were promoted, however, the new variable is only equal to 1 for employee X since they had prior experience at a conglomerate firm.

I can't seem to think of a solution or find my way around this problem. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lag(cumany(.))` after arranging by `date` to determine if an `employee` previously met the condition.

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(employee) %>%
  mutate(prior = (rolename == "CEO") & lag(cumany(company_conglomerate > 0))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#   date       employee company rolename company_conglomerate prior
#   <date>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                   <int> <lgl>
# 1 2008-12-31 X        A       manager                     1 FALSE
# 2 2008-12-31 Y        B       manager                     0 FALSE
# 3 2008-12-31 Z        C       manager                     0 FALSE
# 4 2009-12-31 Y        A       CEO                         1 FALSE
# 5 2009-12-31 X        B       CEO                         0 TRUE 
# 6 2009-12-31 Z        C       CEO                         0 FALSE
```

Note that since we're ordering by `date`, we need to format it for better sorting.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(date = c("31-12-2008", "31-12-2008", "31-12-2008", "31-12-2009", "31-12-2009", "31-12-2009"), employee = c("X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "X", "Z"), company = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), rolename = c("manager", "manager", "manager", "CEO", "CEO", "CEO"), company_conglomerate = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by checking the cumulative sum of the prior conglomerate status:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(employee) %>% 
  mutate(expe = (rolename == "CEO" & (cumsum(company_conglomerate)-company_conglomerate)>0)*1)
```

Output:

```
  date       employee company rolename company_conglomerate  expe
  <chr>      <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                   <int> <dbl>
1 31-12-2008 X        A       manager                     1     0
2 31-12-2008 Y        B       manager                     0     0
3 31-12-2008 Z        C       manager                     0     0
4 31-12-2009 Y        A       CEO                         1     0
5 31-12-2009 X        B       CEO                         0     1
6 31-12-2009 Z        C       CEO                         0     0
```